# Creating product with bundle from api

Tags: api, product, demandware

I'm trying to create a product and bundle with another existing product referring this [document](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/OCAPI/current/data/Resources/Products.html?cp=0_12_4_34). It creates the Bundle1 but doesn't assign to it the specified Product1 as bundle. Any help would be nice, thank you.

End point I'm using to create the product:

```
/s/-/dw/data/${ApiVersion}/products/Bundle1 (Method PUT)
```

This is the body of the request:

```
{
        "bundled_products":[{
             "id":"Product1"
          }],
        "id" : "Bundle1",
        "name": "Bundle 1",
        "online_flag": true,
        "owning_catalog_id": "master-catalog",
        "searchable": true,
        "type" :{
         "bundle" : true
        }
    }
```